# How to use the Storage Attach Service for public storage access instead of private storage access?

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

### Problem Summary

My app (in development), when run on the desktop, can both:

- Write to & read from private storage
- Write to & read from public storage.

However, when run on Android, only private storage is accessible.

### How To Replicate The Issue

Instead of sharing excerpts of my project's codebase, let me refer to another codebase we share and have - the [gluon-connect-file-provider](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/gluon-connect-file-provider) project in [Gluon Samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples). The sample apps only demonstrate private storage usage. None demonstrate public storage usage, so in the gluon-connect-file-provider project, you can make the following change in *com.gluonhq.samples.connect.file.Main.java*:

**Before**

```
static {
    ROOT_DIR = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                .flatMap(StorageService:getPrivateStorage)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error retrieving private storage"));
}
```

**After**

```
static {
    ROOT_DIR = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                .flatMap(s -> s.getPublicStorage("Gluon"))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error retrieving public storage"));
    ROOT_DIR.mkdir();
}
```

When starting the app on the Desktop after this change, you can first observe the directory *~/Gluon* being created on your machine. Then, as you toggle the checkbox on/off in the app's Object Viewer screen, you can also confirm the underlying JSON file *~/Gluon/user.json* is being updated. So, therefore, we can agree public storage works.

However, when deployed to Android, we can see file-permission related failures in the scrolling terminal during *mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:nativerun*. First, the Gluon directory fails to be created at startup and, consequently later, attempts to write the *user.json* file occur.

I thought the soluton was to define in the project the file *src/android/AndroidManifest.xml*. The default found at *target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gensrc/android/AndroidManifest.xml* does not include the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

So, I copied the generated *AndroidManifest.xml* file to *src/android*, including these entries to it. Even though the Android Settings shows me my app has Storage Permission, this still didn't resolve the problem.

Note - when preparing this post asking for your help, I noticed that, without also provisioning *src/android/AndroidManifest.xml* file with EXTERNAL READ/WRITE permissions for the gluon-connect-file-provider, the Android device already showed the deployed app had Storage Permission enabled.

I used two different Android devices to test with.

1. Pixel XL running Android version 10.
2. Samsung S9 running Android version 10.

I tested with the latest GluonHQ Attach dependency 4.0.13 and also with the oldest I found available, 4.0.7.

Is there something more that must be done for the Storage Attach Service to allow public storage access on Android? Please tell me how else to modify the gluon-connect-file-provider app to make it so, thank you.

Comment: You might want to check the StorageService [JavaDoc](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/storage/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/attach/storage/StorageService.java#L85), and also the implementation details [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/storage/src/main/native/android/dalvik/DalvikStorageService.java#L49). I'll start by testing `Documents` for instance.

Comment: I've been troubleshooting this for days, @José Pereda. I'm starting to think we've found a defect. Do you concur? Should we repost this as an official bug report? Or are you and other Gluon experts still looking into this?

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug. You can’t use any random location on your phone, most of it is restricted. There are already a few open folders, like Documents, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, @JoséPereda. I tried everything for Android. After trying to programmatically create a sub-folder didn't work, or manually creating one on behalf of the app, I then tried using well known pre-existing folders like "Documents" or "Download". Nothing works. We cannot accomplish public storage access.

Comment: If you have Android 10, you can try the new Attach 4.0.14-SNAPSHOT, it should work for you. Add `<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>` to your Maven repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolution

Update to [Gluon Attach](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/attach/) 4.0.14.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

With this update, Storage Service will allow you to access pre-existing Android folders, like "Documents" for example. Or, as seen in this post's code excerpt above, you can define your own new directory like "Gluon", or naming the folder after your own App.

### Extra

Another cascading result of this Attach update is, in addition to [Storage Service](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.storage/com/gluonhq/attach/storage/package-summary.html), file sharing via the [Share Service](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.share/com/gluonhq/attach/share/package-summary.html) is now available on Android. Its [JavaDoc](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.share/com/gluonhq/attach/share/ShareService.html) states Storage Service as a requirement to use Share Service. Below is a quote from its [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.share/com/gluonhq/attach/share/ShareService.html):

> Note that on Android, the file has to be located in a public folder
> (see StorageService#getPublicStorage), or sharing it won't be allowed.