# StorageService.create() Always Returns Empty

Tags: gluon, gluon-desktop

I'm developing a Gluon application on a Windows 10 machine using IntelliJ Ultimate.  Whenever I call:

```
StorageService.create()
```

I get an Optional.empty returned to me.  In the application output, I see:

```
com.gluonhq.attach.util.impl.DefaultServiceFactory createInstance
WARNING: No new instance for interface com.gluonhq.attach.storage.StorageService and class com.gluonhq.attach.storage.impl.DesktopStorageService
May 26, 2022 8:37:25 PM com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.tracking.TrackingManager <clinit>
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Private storage file not available
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.0.6/com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.tracking.TrackingManager.lambda$static$0(TrackingManager.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.0.6/com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.tracking.TrackingManager.<clinit>(TrackingManager.java:28)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.0.6/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.continueInit(MobileApplication.java:266)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.0.6/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(MobileApplication.java:232)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

What can I do to make private storage available to me while developing my app?

Comment: Here is a [snippet](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/21793bdd11c9e4e4b9192861f5cfebe762678c1c/gluon-connect-file-provider/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/samples/connect/file/Main.java#L52) from gluon-samples repository accessing StorageService's private storage.

Comment: You should make this an answer instead of a comment so that I can give you points!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which maven version of the attach service Storage you're using but I found a bug earlier that was patched. See this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484071/16394182